# Tanstack react query

Tags: reactjs, axios, fetch, react-query, tanstackreact-query

In the react query v3 or less there are onSuccess onError callbacks, i used them a lot and i find them important.

```
const {data, isLoading} = useQuery("my_key", myFunctionThatReturnsPromise, {
 // other settings,
 onSuccess: (data) => // do something on success,
 onError: (data) => // do something on error,
})
```

There isn't **onSuccess** and **onError** in the new tenstack query.... How do i handle errors?
Do i simply just write my own async try catch function insead of just myFunctionThatReturnsPromise.

How can i use **onSuccess** and **onError** in tenstack query :( ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution depends on what you were putting into those callbacks. A few examples:

#### Global error handling

If you want default error handling that applies to all of your queries, you should set that up just once when creating your query client. For example:

```
const queryClient = new QueryClient({
  queryCache: new QueryCache({
    onError: (error) => {
      console.error('Uh oh', error.message);
    }
  }),
})
```

If you want to modify this for individual queries, you can use the `meta` option to provide data on how to handle the error. For example, if you want each query to provide its own custom error message:

```
const queryClient = new QueryClient({
  queryCache: new QueryCache({
    onError: (error, meta) => {
      toast(meta.errorMessage);
    }
  }),
})

// elsewhere:
useQuery({
  queryKey: ['items'],
  queryFn: fetchItems,
  meta: {
    errorMessage: 'Failed to fetch items',
  },
})
```

#### Using error for rendering

If you were using the onError to set some local state, which then gets used in the render calculation, instead use the values returned by useQuery itself to drive that ui. For example:

```
const { data, isError } = useQuery({
  queryKey: ['items'],
  queryFn: fetchItems,
});

if (isError) {
  return <div>Uh oh, something went wrong</div>
}
// ...
```

#### Error side effects

If you're doing some side effect (eg, logging, showing a toast, navigating to a different page), put that into a useEffect.

```
const { data, isError } = useQuery({
  queryKey: ['items'],
  queryFn: fetchItems,
});

useEffect(() => {
  if (isError) {
    console.error('Uh oh')
    navigate(-1);
  }
}, [isError]);
```

#### Request level error handling

Sometimes you'll have error handling which is closely related to the specific request. Like maybe you want to normalize error codes, or replace a 404 with a success that returns null. This sort of handling it typically best put in the query function (`myFunctionThatReturnsPromise` in your example)

```
const myFunctionThatReturnsPromise = async () => {
  try {
    return await axios.get(/* ... */);  
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.response.status === 404) {
      return null;
    } else {
      throw error;
    }
  }
}
```

---

If you have any specific cases that you don't think fit with these categories, please feel free to mention them in the comments.

Comment: I always knew that i could simply make a functionality inside my:

```
const myFunctionThatReturnsPromise = async () => {
  try {
    return await axios.get(/* ... */);  
  } catch (error) {
      // do something with my error
  }
}
```

But hell, i'll miss onError onSuccess callbacks :(

Comment: what were you doing in the callbacks please?